# Why are my timer and score count not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to create a game using action script 3 and can't understand why the following code is resulting in my score immediately resetting to 0 and my timer rapidly changing numbers with no consistent pattern? Any help is much appreciated! Thank You!

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var score:int=0;
var nCount:Number = 5;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000, nCount);
timer_txt.text = nCount.toString();

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.start();

function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void{
    nCount--;
    timer_txt.text = nCount.toString();
}
init();
function init(): void {
    Mouse.hide();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkIfHit);
}

function update(myEvent:Event):void{
    aim_mc.x = this.mouseX;
    aim_mc.y = this.mouseY;
    score_txt.text = "Score: " + score;
}

function checkIfHit(e:MouseEvent):void{
    for(var i:int = 1; i < 4;++i){
        var myClip:MovieClip = MovieClip(getChildByName("duck" + i));
        if (myClip.hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true)){
            score = score + 1;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var score:int=0;`

you defined the variable but also instantiating with 0. So every frame change your score rollbacks to its _default_ value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @coner in his comment, I think that you have another frame that, maybe, you have added by mistake, and that's why your animation is initialized everytime :

[image]

To avoid that, if you need that frame (these frames) for any reason, you can add a `stop()` in your first one and then you can use `gotoAndStop()` or `gotoAndPlay()` in another time to change the frame, or if you don't need that frame and you've added by mistake, you have just to remove it.

Also, don't forget to remove the event listeners and to stop your game after that your countdown is finished ...

Hope that can help.

Comment: it does seem like the playhead is coming back over and over to that frame. Well spotted.

Comment: Thank you so much! I removed the frames and it solved my problem. Good catch!